# フォームにaタグのパラメータを入れたい

Tags: html

案件サイトの制作をしていまして行き詰っております。

各詳細ページの【応募する】ボタンを押すとフォームに飛ぶ形で、フォームページではどの案件の応募かを解るように【応募する】のaタグを押した時に案件ページのURLをパラメーターとして
フォームに送り、フォーム内に自動入力をしたいです。

受け取る側の設定はできたのですが、受け渡す側（aタグ部分）の書き方が解らなく、ご教授お願いいたします。

現在は直リンクで`https://aaa.html?aaa.html`のようにaタグに入れています。

Comment: その「https://aaa.html?aaa.html」直書きの方法でなにか不都合なのでしょうか?

Comment: 具体的なHTMLを質問文に含めて貰った方が回答も付きやすいと思います。 / 「ボタン」というと通常はフォームの送信(Submit)ボタンを想像しますが、質問ではAタグ(ハイパーリンク)との説明が入り混じっているように見えます。

Comment: これ [パラメータを渡してのページ遷移](https://qiita.com/ekzemplaro/items/f62d9c9fe61e7eeb3b8f) とかが参考になるのでは？